# Q: use rejection sampling for true random number generation in a range (entropy from radioactive decay)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, random, entropy

Hi everyone I have been doing some reading and have come across true random number generation using the entropy from radioactive decay. I have written a helper tool that returns the next random byte. It uses a server that provides bits from such a setup, I believe its data is from cesium decaying. I have done quite a bit of searching and have not really been able to figure out how to go about using this to generate numbers in a range from 0..n-1.

A user on the unofficial SO irc told me this

> if you have a random byte, 0..255 evenly distributed and you want a random number in the range 0..5 there are 6 values in the output range and 256 in the input range the greatest multiple of 6 that is <= 256 is 252 so you would sample your random byte until you get a number in the range 0..251 then you could take the number MOD 6 to get your output number.

Im not really sure how to sample the byte. Do I use a single byte or do I have to continually request more bytes? Im really just having a hard time rapping my head around this, so any thorough explanation not using obscure math notations would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Sampling" means (*Disclaimer: not the dictionary definition*) "repeatedly checking for a value", so in your case you'd read bytes until you get one in the proper range, discarding the others.

Comment: That seems extremely data intensive. Is it possible to do the same with less consumption of random bytes, perhaps based on just bit positions?

Comment: Frankly put, I'm probably as reliable (or even less) than the guy on IRC. Randomness is difficult to get right, so every time you come up with some sort of short-cut, it most likely results in the quality of your randomness decreasing.

Comment: @DevinWall If by extremely you mean an average of 1.01 input bytes per output number, then I guess so. You can use individual bits to get more output density per input byte, but there's no getting around throwing away some values probabilistically if you want an even distribution of output values.

Comment: @Nick Johnson maybe I'm doing this wrong then, but since each byte is random wouldn't it be possible to use n bytes per output in a desired range?

Comment: @DevinWall When you say `n`, do you mean you want to use `n` bits out of the byte? You only have 8 bits, if you use 7 your range is going to be `0..127`.

Comment: @beaker no I was just asking about the wasted data. Nick said the average 1.01 input bytes per output number. However that doesn't sound right to me. Its possibly my misunderstanding of this, but it seems like for every rejection you have to request a new byte. So to get one valid output within the desired range you could use n bytes from your byte pool trying to get a number in the desired range. Or am I way off?

Comment: @DevinWall No, what Nick said was that for every 1000 random numbers you need to generate, you will, on average, generate 1010 numbers and reject 10 of them. (Actually, I think the real number might be closer to 16.) I have no idea what you mean by "byte pool".

Comment: @DevinWall, beaker is correct - if 252/256 values result in an output, you only have to sample again 4/256 = ~1.6% of the time, so the average number of bytes per output number is only very slightly over one.